# How can I import local hosted MySQL database to PlanetScale

Tags: mysql, import, planetscale

Am making a website, hosted on netlify, and i've made the database on MySQL workbench, how do I import it into my PlanetScale? to be live.

I've tried to watch the planetscale tutorial for that.

Can I do some command that can run to get me a file that can be imported?

Some usefull info:
1- I have it on workbench, so I cant really see the database files
2- My planet scale tier is the free one, so i dont know if i can import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to have some instruction here on how to import data from a database that you have.

https://planetscale.com/docs/imports/database-imports

You might use some free tier hosting provided by a cloud provider to publicly host your db and then use this import client they have.

Alternatively, you might simply run `mysql-dump` on your existing database to create a dump.sql file with your existing db, and then run that dump file with the mysql client of your choice pointed at your planetscale db to create the database.

Comment: I couldn't understand!, i ran mysqldump using --all-databases, where is the dump.sql file? what is the mysql client that i should use? at least suggest one, what is a cloud provider? and why can't i directly import this db to planetscale? it have this command
mysql --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY --ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
This command is in the planetscale docs, but my verification method is password, not SSL cert.